# Problems creating ragged hierarchy with Analysis Services

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssas, olap

I'm attempting to create a ragged hierarchy in SSAS 2005. The "Category Name" and "Sub-Category Name" levels should be hidden in the hierarchy if either of them is blank. Leaf nodes which always have a value must display even if these two levels are blank.

An image of how the measure has been configured is as follows:

[Measure dimension http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/9468/dimmeasuretrim.png](http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/9468/dimmeasuretrim.png)

I thought using HideMemberIf would fix this problem but it hasn't made any difference. Here is the Translations configuration:

[Dimension translations http://img37.imageshack.us/img37/3710/dimmeasuretranstrim.png](http://img37.imageshack.us/img37/3710/dimmeasuretranstrim.png)

According to MSDN, [HideMemberIf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms129445%28SQL.90%29.aspx) with a NoName value hides the member when it is empty.

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was pretty simple. The **MDX Compatibility** property needs to be set to 2 for this to work correctly.

[See TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365406.aspx) for more information.